# Symmetric random walk and Borel-Cantelli

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk, symmetry, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of i.i.d. r.v. such that $\mathbb{P}(X_n=1)=\mathbb{P}(X_n=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$

Also let $$S_n= \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k$$
I am asked to show, using Borel–Cantelli lemma, that for every (integer) $k \geq 1$

$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}(S_{n+k}-S_n)=k\ \ \ \ \   \text{a.s.} $$

I am not sure how to interpret this and how to prove it.

My interpretation is that we are considering the events $A_n=\{(S_{n+k}-S_n)=k\}$

Then $$\sum \mathbb{P}(A_n) = \infty$$

but the events are not independent so we can not conlude with Borel–Cantelli lemma that

$$\mathbb{P} (A_n  \ \ \text{i.o.}) = \mathbb{P}(\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}(S_{n+k}-S_n)=k) = 1 $$

My other idea was to show that the event  "$A_n$ occours infinitely often" is a tail event, then by Fatou's lemma I could say that  $$\mathbb{P}(\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}(S_{n+k}-S_n)=k) \geq \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k$$ and conclude by Kolmogorov 0-1 theorem...

I am not really sure and any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Hint: take a deterministic subsequence $n_j$ so that the events $\{S_{n_j + k} - S_{n_j} = k\}$ are independent.

Comment: thanks! I could just take $n_j= j k$ I guess it is very similar to Davide's answer...

Is the Fatou's Lemma bit just wrong, on the other hand?

Comment: That's another way to do the problem.  It just doesn't use Borel Cantelli.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Borel-Cantelli lemma with 
$$B_n:=\bigcap_{j=nk+1}^{(n+1)k}\{X_j=1\}.$$

Comment: so essentially with $A_{nk}$, then I say that the fact that $B_n$ occurs infinitely many times implies that $A_n$ occurs infinitely many times and conculude?

Comment: Yes (and also because $S_{n+k}-S_n\leqslant k$).